# Unable to catch .NET errors in IronPython

Tags: error-handling, ironpython

i could not error handling Error from .NET Dll when call different methods of an object. I got this error with IronPython:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>     at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>     at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>     at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
>     at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

I added try and exception as:

```py
import System
for i in dir(object):
    try:
        getattr(object,i)()
    expcept  System.AccessViolationException as e:
        print i,e
    expcept  Exception as e:
        print i,e
```

However, the `Unhandled Exception` still crashes my code. How to make error handling in this case.

Comment: Where does the object come from? If this is an actual unmanaged AccessViolationException (not raised by managed user code) it won't be catched.

Comment: It's an object from a .NET dll library for C#. Have any way to get console output to file so that i could parse output and find the affected method ?